# Website renders differently on IE9 for different computers

Tags: html, css, web, internet-explorer-9

I recently built my first ever published site. www.adenschoolofmotoring.co.uk Problem is that when I view it in IE9 I get rendering issues.

The strange thing is that my home laptop uses IE9 and will render fine but when I use my work laptop with the same browser, IE9 the rendering is all over the place.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this is the case? If I wrote a separate CSS script for IE would I get the same problem?

Cheers

Comment: I would guess one computer has IE in Quirks Mode, while the other on default. You might fix it by implementing a `<!DOCTYPE...>`

Comment: What are the rendering issues you see? Also, re: above, it's rendering in standards mode for me so it doesn't look like the doctype.

Comment: are both machines running the same operating system, as well?  that can make a difference too

Answer (score 1):

Saw this code in your source:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<html>
    <link href="adencss.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <div class="container">
        <div id="header">
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
            <title> Home- Aden School of Motoring</title>

            <div id="logohead">
                <div id="imagelog">
                    <a href = "index.html"><img src="images/adentran.png" width="350" height="130"/></a>
                </div>

                <div id="slogan">
                    <img src="images/slogan.gif" width="200" height="70"/>
                </div>
            </div>

                <div id="navMenu">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="index.html">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Prices.html">Prices</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Coverage.html">Coverage</a></li>
                        <li><a href="Contacts.html">Contacts</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Resources</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>


            </head>

            <div class="push"></div>
        </div>

        <body>
                <div id="homeblurb">
```

Not only are you defining 2 html tags but you are rendering a `<div>` outside of a `<body>` tag. Inside that `<div class='container'>` you also have the head tag. You might try fixing your markup and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that one of the computers has had the browser settings changed.  Some browsers allow the user to specify the style-settings for common HTML tags like  through  and so on...    To check this open the browser and go to: Tools > Internet Options >  At the bottom-right of the General tab, click the "Accessibility" button.  If anything is checking in here, or the "User style sheet" is active, it will be over-writing the CSS from the site.